# Combining two Object with multiple keys using angular 2

Tags: json, angular, rxjs, associative-array

I have two object, second should be merge or combined with the first array that results a new array.

```
this.firstArray = [{
   "field": "A",
   "value": ["1","2"]
   },{
   "field": "B",
   "value": ["1","2","3"]
   }]    

this.secondArray = [{
    "type": "A",
    "option": 1,
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "type": "A",
    "option": 2,
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "type": "B",
    "option": 1,
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "type": "B",
    "option": 3,
    "count": 1
  }]
```

**Desired Output:** 
Conditions:

- Field and Type should be the same
- Value and Options should also be the same
- return the count
- return **0** if none found in second Array

  ```
  [{
     "field": "A",
     "value": ["1": 2,"2": 1]
     },{
     "field": "B",
     "value": ["1": 1,"2": 0,"3": 1]
     }]
  ```

What I did was just appending the json to its field that has the same field and type..

```
this._finalArr = this.firstArray.map(val => {
          return Object.assign({}, val, this.secondArray.filter(v => v.field === val.type)[0]);
            });
            console.log(this._finalArr);
```

Comment: https://ng-run.com/edit/VPhIEPVucHMbX250GVPo

Comment: please add it to answer so i can vote for it.. also using this approach how could I access the count or value using "let v of q.value" i tried {{q.data[i].value}} but none works